# Jetstream User Profile Update: problems passing $input[] field using Livewire form input

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I added some custom fields to the User Model and it stores them perfectly during registration (country_id, city_id, and state_id), but I am having problems with the profile management/update:

The fields seem to update only when using the jetstream components as input but NOT when I use my dropdown select option input

```
<x-jet-input id="cap" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="state.cap" />
```

So for instance this would update the $input['cap'] key but the "country_id" field from my livewire script does not update the $input['country_id'] ...

```
<select wire:model="selectedCountry" id="country_id" name="country_id">
 <option value="{{$user->country_id}}"> {{$user->country->name}} </option>
            @foreach($countries as $country)
                <option value="{{$country->id}}"> {{$country->name}} </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <x-jet-input-error for="country_id" class="mt-2" />
```

To display or hide fields for instance I update the variables such as $SelectedCountry

The  Country/City/State fields are displayed using a livewire script that hides or shows a given select dropdown and runs queries only when needed (if a Country has states/regions, it shows them otherwise it shows only the cities from the selected country etc).

If I submit though, the $input['country_id'] key is not changing though and it just keeps the previous value with which I registered.

I assume the jetstream component would do using wire:model.defer="state.country_id" for instance but again I can not use it because is just a text input... any ideas?

Update-Profile-information-Form

```
...
        <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
            <x-jet-label for="cap" value="{{ __('Postal Code') }}" />
            <x-jet-input id="cap" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="state.cap" />
            <x-jet-input-error for="cap" class="mt-2" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
            <x-jet-label for="address" value="{{ __('Address') }}" />
            <x-jet-input id="address" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="state.address" />
            <x-jet-input-error for="address" class="mt-2" />
        </div>


        <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
            @livewire('edit-address', ['user' => Auth::user()])
        </div>
...
```

edit-address.blade.php (view)

```
<div>
...
        <x-jet-label for="country_id" value="{{ __('Country') }}" />
        <select wire:model="selectedCountry" id="country_id" name="country_id">
            <option value="{{$user->country_id}}"> {{$user->country->name}} </option>
            @foreach($countries as $country)
                <option value="{{$country->id}}"> {{$country->name}} </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <x-jet-input-error for="country_id" class="mt-2" />
    </div>
...
```

EditAdress.php (livewire script)

```
class EditAddress extends Component
{
    public $countries;
    public $states;
    public $cities;


    public $selectedCountry = null;
    public $selectedState = null;
    public $selectedCity = null;
    public $test = null;
    public $user = null;


    public function mount(User $user, $selectedCity = null){
        $this->countries = Country::all();

        $this->states = collect();
        $this->cities = collect();
        $this->selectedCity = $selectedCity;

        if (!is_null($selectedCity)) {
            $city = City::with('state.country')->find($selectedCity);
            if ($city) {

                /*if ($this->states->isEmpty()===1){
                    $this->cities = City::where('country_id', $this->selectedCountry);
                }*/

                $this->cities = City::where('state_id', $city->state_id)->get();
                $this->states = State::where('country_id', $city->state->country_id)->get();
                $this->selectedCountry = $city->state->country_id;
                $this->selectedState = $city->state_id;
            }
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.edit-address');
    }

    public function updatedSelectedCountry($country)
    {
        ;
        $this->states = State::where('country_id', $country)->get();
        $this->selectedState = NULL;

        if(!$this->states->count()){
            $this->cities = City::where('country_id', $country)->get();
        }

    }

    public function updatedSelectedState($state)
    {
        if (!is_null($state)) {

            $this->cities = City::where('state_id', $state)->get();
        }
        else{

            $this->cities = City::where('country_id', $this->selectedCountry);
        }


    }
    

    }
```

Comment: Remember define the rules for the property when you bind directly from a Model, like address.street

Comment: I'm a bit confused: in the laravel script, the inputs Country, State and City are wired to some variables not directly to the model and then the content of these variables are passed via the form to the UpdateUserProfileInformation.php where I have validation etc... am I missing something? 

Comment: dd in the updatedSelectedCountry dump something?